# share text on twitter with consumer key at objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, twitter

i want to post NSString with my consumer key and secret on twitter, using objective c. usually everyone use twitter library which is in xcode. but the library in xcode send without consumer key and secret. so i found a sample code from http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/adding-twitter-support-ios-5-with-oauth-fallback-to-your-ios-app-with-rsoauthengine/

that code is run successfully but i have to convert arc project from Edit/Refactor/Convert to Objective C ARC...  menu. when i do this all of my running other codes give error. i just want to send sample text with consumer key and secret. thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can user sharekit for that

**configure ShkConfig file**

```
#define SHKTwitterSecret            @"r43dw1kQyCB3AGs1vDai6C7wCxUhQlIIKr0rp5vU"
#define SHKTwitterCallbackUrl       @"https://www.google.com"
```

**in your .m file**

```
#import "SHK.h"
#import "SHKTwitter.h"

SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:@"textmeg"];
[SHKTwitter shareItem:item];
```

Comment: i downloaded share kit and imported my project. but i take an error that #import </usr/include/objc/objc-class.h> file not found. is this class my UIView class?

Comment: i changed </usr/include/objc/objc-class.h> to <objc/objc-class.h>. and the error was finish.after that project gives 20 errors.their examples doesn't run. do you have any running example?

Comment: i imported this library and write that codes. as you know, first authentication window appears. i want to share text when i enter my user name and password. but it redirect my redirect url and window don't close automatically.do you have a running example.

Comment: you have to pass the same callback url which you have set at time of generating  TwitterSecret key.

Answer (score 0):

Use [sharekit](http://getsharekit.com/) for authentication and sending text message as its easy to use

Download [Sharekit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/downloads) from here.When error occurs follow [this](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tag/objcobjc-class-h) link

Comment: this error is one of share kit errors    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SHK.o
      anon in SHKMail.o
      objc-class-ref in SHKMail.o
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_MFMailComposeViewController_$_SHK in SHKMail.o. do you have any running sample please?

Comment: i found solution. i imported security.framework and some framework. thank you Prince and SmartWork.

Comment: sharekit doesn't work. i wrote an e-mail sharekit team. they send me automatic reply. sharekit is doesn't share anything

Comment: what problem not found sharekit code or not able share.To share u will have to login first.

Comment: i found upgrade to sharekit. there are a lot of upgrades for sharekit. first i found cancel button upgrade. after post url update.... finally i can get run sharing. thank you Prince for your help.